# Terraform - cannot source module from github

Tags: terraform, terraform-template-file

I am trying to source a terraform module from github like so:

```
module "example" {
  source = "https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-example-module.git?ref=master"
  example = "Hello world!"
}
```

When I run `terraform init`, I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to download module

Could not download module "example" (main.tf:6) source code from
"https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-example-module.git?ref=master": error
downloading
'https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-example-module.git?ref=master': no
source URL was returned
```

I confrimed that the repo does infact exist.. what am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There shouldn't be `https://` at the beginning. So it should be:

```
module "example" {
  source  = "github.com/cloudposse/terraform-example-module.git?ref=master"
  example = "Hello world!"
}
```